# Cordova/AngularJS $http.get always cached

Tags: angularjs, cordova, http, caching, get

Checking server message when an app is opened every time.

On Android this message is always cached.
When the server is offline a cached message is returned.
Which also is a problem because then for certain a message should be shown (default error message or a timeout).

Have tried the following:

```
$http.get(url, { cache: false }) ...
```

And before

```
$cacheFactory.get('$http').removeAll();
```

Even

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Also in module index:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider)
{
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get)
    {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }
}])
```

On IOS the value does not seem cached instead, except for when the server is offline.

Answer (score 1):

You can either install a Cordova plugin to disable the cache for Android and IOS:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-disable-http-cache
```

Or you can check [this solution](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-disable-cache-on-http-get/21594/9) at the ionic forum.

```js
myApp.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q',function($q) {
var regex = new RegExp('\.(html|js|css)$','i');
var isAsset = function(url){
    return regex.test(url);
};
return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
        // do something on success
        if(!isAsset(config.url)){            //if the call is not for an asset file
            config.url+= "?ts=" +  Date.now();     //append the timestamp
        }
        return config;
    },

    // optional method
    'requestError': function(rejection) {
        // do something on error
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    },



    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
        // do something on success
        return response;
    },

    // optional method
    'responseError': function(rejection) {
        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
};
}]);

//appended the interceptor in the config block using $httpProvider
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
```